# pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed. error while inserting data into collection mongodb in python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query

i am trying to insert data into the mongodb collection but showing error 
`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed`

**i am using python 3.6**

my code is pointing towards collection now `self.col.insert({"a":"b"})`

Comment: I don't think this is due to the little part of code you show. This is a matter of connection with the database of mongo.

Comment: i include my docker entry point file in the docker compose container but their my docker entry point file is not running showing error in log 

 [main] In File::open(), ::open for '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_user.js' failed with Permission denied

Comment: I don't use docker, so unfortunately I cannot help on part concerned by docker. Did you check if mongo were already running?

Comment: issue resolved the issue was the no permission of add_user file